# Does .rspec file get run every time rspec runs?

Tags: ruby, rspec

Does the `.rspec` file you get when initializing the project, get run every time you run your tests (through `rspec [file location]`) ? Just curious because inside the `.rspec` file, using `cat .rspec`, I found that it contains `require spec_helper`. If it does get run every time, this would save me a lot of time from writing `require spec_helper` in each of my test files.

Comment: Have you tested what you are asking?

Comment: Not necessarily how to test given that the configuration file alone doesn't output any output to the screen when testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It gets called every time. You don't need to include it in every spec file.

I have `--require spec_helper` in my `.rspec` file.

[Here's](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-5/docs/configuration/read-command-line-configuration-options-from-files) a link to the `rspec` docs, which includes a list of other options.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, different files are the file loaded when running a spec, in precedence order (where later entries overwrite earlier entries on conflicts):

1 - Global ($XDG_CONFIG_HOME/rspec/options, or ~/.rspec if it does not exist)

2 - Project-specific (./.rspec)

3 - Local (./.rspec-local)

4 - Command-line options SPEC_OPTS

[Here's the link to the official docs for RSpec Core 3.13](https://rspec.info/documentation/3.13/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/Configuration.html)